# Extracting text data from multiple PDF documents

Tags: python, pdf, nlp

I am currently working on a project which requires me to extract text from a particular section of PDFs.
i.e. the Investment Strategy section of an offer document. The problem i am facing is that there is no set template for the offer documents i.e. the Investment Strategy section has no fixed place in the document. Each document might have a different preceding/following section to the Investment Strategy. Is there a python library available which i can leverage here.

Regards,
Ujwal

```
import io
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

import re
import math
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

path = 'C:/Prospectus'
pathlen=len(path)
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.pdf")]

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):   
    #given the path of the file as argument, the function reads the pdf and returns the text in it
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,
                                  password=password,
                                  caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)        
    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text

file1 = convert_pdf_to_txt(files[0])
file2 = convert_pdf_to_txt(files[1])

words11 = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-z]*',file1)
words12 = re.findall(r"\w+",file1)
words21 = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-z]*',file2)
words22 = re.findall(r"\w+",file2)
```

Comment: I've had luck with `pdfminer.high_level.extract_text` and then finding a usable pattern in the extracted text. Your mileage may vary.